# Generic function, Where T limitations

Tags: c#

I was reading this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx to understand if I can limit my function to use basic or limited set of data type only. Basically I am writing a function that should work for int, double, float, single, string, DateTime only. so how can I limit my generic function to this?

Comment: What kind of thing can you do with int, double, float, string _and_ DateTime? (single and float are the same thing).

Comment: well I am writing a DB wrapper function, and return array of data of one column, so I need it such that all possible datatype are covered that are supported by DB. nothing much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't constrain a type parameter to only a specific collection of types. The closest you can come is to see what interfaces they all have in common, and constrain it to a type which implements those.

For example:

```
public void Foo<T>() where T : IComparable, IConvertible, IComparable<T>,
    IEquatable<T>
```

It still wouldn't actually prevent other types which implement all of those interfaces, however. (And even then it has to be the strict intersection of all of the interfaces involved - for example, `string` doesn't implement `IFormattable` or `ISerializable`, so those can't be on the list.)

You could always use those interfaces as a first filter, however, and then do an *execution-time* check using `typeof(T)`, throwing an exception if it's not in the accepted set.

Comment: as you pointed out, does it cover my basic string, int, float/double, DateTime... in it ?

Comment: @SumitGupta: Yes, I believe that list of interfaces is covered by all of them - but it would *also* include `Guid`, for example.

Comment: The listed types don't have a whole lot in common.  I'd say that it would be best to skip the type constraints on the method, do a check with `typeof(T)`, and throw an exception if the method is called with an unsupported type parameter.

Comment: @Dan: It depends what the method is meant to do. If it needs to take two values of the same type, for example, then it could still be worth making it generic. Or if it actually *uses* all of those interfaces. Even without that, just avoiding *some* compile-time mistakes *may* be appropriate. Also, if there are any parameters of type `T` then using generics will avoid the boxing involved in taking `object`.

Answer (score 2):

They are all value types.. so you could limit it to that:

```
public void YourFunction<T>() where T : struct // struct means only value types
```

Really it depends on your use case though..

EDIT:

I didn't realise you included `string` in your list. I missed that one.. the above won't work for that.

Comment: I see that is best near too, but don't it take something like my custom struct define using struct keyword? like struct ABC { int a; int b; } ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct (which is what `DateTime` is). That's the only way you will be able to to limit things to be roughly what you've asked for. Since they are BCL types.. you're unlikely to find any other constraint that fits (I can't think of one off the top of my head..).

Comment: So, considering this, I cannot fully limit it to what I want, but roughly. Well that works for my scenario, but just feels like this is new feature MS will add someday. :). Thanks

Comment: `string` isn't a value type.

Comment: Strings are not value types.

Comment: @JonSkeet Whoops.. missed that one.

Comment: @JonSkeet if string is not a value type, then int and double are ? Any read on that one ? thanks.

Comment: @SumitGupta: Yes, `int` and `double` are value types... I'm not sure what you mean by "Any read on that one"

Comment: @JonSkeet a link or ebook where I can read about them been value type or not :).

Comment: Sumit, this book is pretty good for learning C#: http://www.amazon.com/Depth-3rd-Edition-Jon-Skeet/dp/161729134X. What do you think @JonSkeet? :P

Comment: @SumitGupta: Look at the documentation on MSDN - if it shows the declaration as `struct` or `enum`, it's a value type. If it shows the declaration as `interface`, `class` or `delegates` it's a reference type.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: C# in Depth assumes you know that sort of thing already, to be honest.

Comment: IIRC you cover it fairly quickly early on don't you? Maybe I was thinking of another book..

Answer (score 0):

The listed types don't have much in common.  It sounds like the only reason for implementing this with a generic method is to avoid boxing or having to cast the return value to a specific type.  I would do something like the following:

```
public class Example
{
    private static readonly HashSet<Type> supportedTypes = new HashSet<Type>
    {
        typeof(int),
        typeof(double),
        typeof(float),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(DateTime),
    };

    public T MyMethod<T>()
    {
        if (!this.supportedTypes.Contains(typeof(T))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```